# Smooth mouseover images inside scaled Flex App?

Tags: image, apache-flex, scale, mouseover, smoothing

I have a flex app I am scaling using systemManager.stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER; for the most part it works well except for my bitmap data (mostly png's from the designers).

I can set the mx:image tags to smoothBitmapContent=true and that works great for everything except my mouseover objects.  When I do a mouseover, the source is being changed from one embedded image to another embedded image. I have tried several (many) online "smoothimage" classes, and tried to write my own, I have tried to reset smoothBitmapContent every chance I get but still no dice.  It seems to mee that because I am scaling at the app level, that the flopped out bitmap is not getting smoothed when it renders.

How to keep things smooth? Perhaps there is a flag to tell Flex to smooth stuff when it scales it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easy answer (that works for me) was to instead of changing the image.source from one embedded png to another, was to use two images and flip flop image.visible between the two... Granted that adds two extra objects to the screen, But for some reason they all stay smoothed and scaled that way, where as before switching sources was going from smooth to jaggidy and un-readable.

Josh